# jQuery Ajax Loader/Spinner

Tags: jquery, ajax, comments, toggle

At the moment I have the following jQuery/Ajax in order to load the comments when a user clicks on a div:

```
                function showComments(post_id) {
                    $("#comment-"+post_id).toggle();
                    $.ajax({ 
                         dataType: 'html',
                         cache: false,
                         url: 'ajax.php',
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: {comments: post_id}
                    }).done(function(html) { 
                        $('#comment-'+post_id).html(html)
                    });
                }
```

This all works fine, as the default div has the spinner in it, which is shown until the content has loaded. However, if a user clicks on it again to hide it, then clicks to show again the spinner doesn't appear because the content isn't being reset obviously. So I tried to use .toggles mouse event handler:

```
                function showComments(post_id) {
                    $("#comment-"+post_id).toggle(function() {
                        $('#comment-'+post_id).show();
                        $.ajax({ 
                            dataType: 'html',
                            cache: false,
                            url: 'ajax.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {comments: post_id}
                        }).done(function(html) { 
                            $('#comment-'+post_id).html(html)
                        });   
                    }, function() {
                        $('#comment-'+post_id).hide();
                        $('#comment-'+post_id).html('<img src="/loader.gif" />')
                    });
                }
```

However, this time, nothing works, the div doesn't show, or hide, and the Ajax isn't called. Any ideas what I've perhaps done wrong?

EDIT:

Here's the HTML/PHP:

```
                           <div class="comments right" title="Click to view comments" onclick="showComments('.$post['id'].')">'.$post['comments_cache'].'</div>
                            <div style="display:none" id="comment-'.$post['id'].'" class="top-15"><img src="/loader.gif" /></div>
```

There's nothing wrong with the above, it works fine with the first function I showed you.

Comment: Added the HTML/PHP, even though there's nothing wrong with it, otherwise the first function wouldn't work...

Comment: Turns out I think the .toggle mouse event handler is deprecated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by doing:

```
            function showComments(post_id) {
                if ($('#comment-'+post_id).html().length > 0) {
                    $('#comment-'+post_id).empty().hide();
                } else {
                    $('#comment-'+post_id).html('<img src="loader.gif" />').show();
                    $.ajax({ 
                         dataType: 'html',
                         cache: false,
                         url: 'ajax.php',
                         type: 'POST',
                         data: {comments: post_id}
                    }).done(function(html) { 
                        $('#comment-'+post_id).html(html)
                    }); 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `beforeSend` property of jQuery, and add a class `'open'` to the div once its open to keep track of the display.

```
function showComments(post_id) {
  $("#comment-" + post_id).click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
          $(this).show().addClass('open');
        },
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          comments: post_id
        },
        success: function (html) {
          $(this).html(html);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(this).hide().html('<img src="/loader.gif" />').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
}
```